# Update just a couchbase field from a Couchbase document using the Java SDK

Tags: spring, nosql, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to update just **one** field of a big document, using the Spring-data-Couchbase implementation that uses the Java SDK behind.

[Documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/3.0/howtos/kv-operations.html#replace) points me to retrieve the full document first, then change a field and upsert it completely. Can I optimize it by just updating the field I need to change in a single operation?

Comment: I want something like @DynamicUpdate from Hibernate

Comment: Couchbase SDKs do have a *subdocument* API (more information on the Java one here - https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/subdocument-operations.html). I do not know if Spring Data uses it, but worst case, you can drop down to the plain Couchbase Java SDK.